# What does これで mean in this case?

Tags: grammar

> これで全部じゃないだろう

What does これで mean here?

Basically they were bullying a kid into giving them money and say..."this isn't all, is it?"

Does it mean "that much" (is not all you got, is it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means  "here/with this"

> "With this (money), thats not all there is, right?"

thats the best way i could show it in english.

You already translated it yourself really.